# What kind of problem is the Potter Kata? Is there a general solution?

Tags: algorithms, problem-solving, scoring-algorithm

I recently completed the [Book Store](https://exercism.org/tracks/ruby/exercises/book-store) exercise on [Exercism](https://exercism.org). It is a copy of the Potter Kata from [Coding Dojo](https://codingdojo.org/kata/Potter/).

The basic premise is that a bookstore wants to promote sales of a particular book series. They offer progressively higher discounts on the purchase of multiple books.  The catch is that you have to buy different books from the series to get the discounts.

There are five books in the series, and the discounts are as follows:

- One book is full price, $8, as are multiple copies of the same book.
- Two *different* books will be discounted by 5% each.
- Three different books are discounted 10% each.
- Four different books are discounted 20% each.
- Five books (a complete set) are discounted by 25% each.

The store wants to be able to group any given basket of books to provide the greatest discount. You may note that a basket of one copy of the entire series, plus three more titles, (that is, five books, plus three books) will have a lower price if treated as two groups of four, rather than a group of five and a group of three.

**tl;dr**

1. What type of problem is this? Is it an assignment problem? A variation of the knapsack problem?
2. Is there a general solution that, given a discount scheme, will identify all of the pricing "anomalies," such as the one above?
3. I don't need an answer so much as a pointer in the right direction for inquiry and analysis.

**What I Did**

I wanted to create a solution that did not rely on brute force to examine every possible configuration of a basket, or simply hardcode the correction from 5/3 groupings to 4/4. I came up something that works with this discount scheme and some more contrived schemes, but I am certain it is not generally correct.

The pricing anomaly in this problem occurs because the discount increases by 10% from the third book to the fourth book, rather than 5% as with all of the other jumps. If all of the jumps were the same, it would always be best to take the largest possible grouping. Interestingly, if the disproportionate jump took place on the third book (say, a 15% discount instead of 10%), then I do not believe any anomalies would be created, and it would still be optimal to always take the largest available grouping. In the alternative, if you contrive the discount scheme as two for 5% off, three for 23% off, four for 24% off, and five for 25% off, then a number of anomalies will be created (at least five) and must be accounted for. For example, a basket of 5/5/2 books would be cheaper if charged as 3/3/3/3, and cheaper still if charged as 4/4/4, while a basket of 5/5/5/1 books would be cheaper at 4/4/4/4, but cheaper still at 5/5/3/3.

**My (incorrect) Approach**

My current solution looks for anomaly candidates by analyzing the rate of increase in each discount from the base price for a single book as follows:

| set | discount | discount / (set - 1) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.00 | N/A |
| 2 | 0.05 | 0.05 |
| 3 | 0.10 | 0.05 |
| 4 | 0.20 | 0.667 |
| 5 | 0.25 | 0.625 |

I believe that if the third column either stayed the same or increased with each step, then the "greedy" solution of always taking the largest possible grouping would always be optimal. However, since the factor for four books is larger than the factor for five books, then there *may* be situations where groups of four might be cheaper than groups of five and a smaller group.

Next, I take all of the anomaly candidates and search for situations where multiple groups of the candidate (*e.g.*, 4/4, 4/4/4, etc.) would be preferable to the default, largest first approach (5/3, in this case).

I do not think my approach is correct or efficient. How can I approach this problem more rigorously?

*(Also, please suggest better tags to improve the visibility of this question. Thank you!)*

Comment: This looks like advertisement, to be honest. I don’t think here is the right place for it.

Comment: I think part of the knapsack problem is the fixed "cost" of an item and the capacity limit using those costs on the containers.  There is probably a name for the task of "grouping items to minimize total group scores" but I don't know what it is.  This might be a good way to focus the question: "Is there a name for the mathematical problem called where you try to group items to minimize total cost?"

Comment: I'm not completely sure the rules are clear, but I would expect the solution would grow from the observation that you can always separate duplicate books into separate baskets without changing price, and then merging baskets which are disjoint reduces price.  But then as you observed it seems like there are some unexpected combinations that bring benefits too. It feels a bit like linear programming to me, but maybe not...

Comment: If you've solved the problem, then often these types of sites allow access to explanations of the problem in terms of algorithms and mathematics.  You could check both sites for that information...

Comment: @Merle, advertisement for what? I'm not clear on what you mean. If you mean the links to the sites, I can remove them if they are improper. I put them there for attribution and because they provide more comprehensive descriptions of the problem.

Comment: @rschwleb, thank you for your thoughts. My understanding of knapsack is that there is some constraint, and the problem seeks to maximize (or minimize, in this case) within that constraint. I'm still not sure if this problem falls within that domain. Also, I am not a member of Coding Dojo, but Exercism only offers other published solutions to wade through. I did not see any that calculated a generalized solution that predicts pricing anomalies based solely on the discount scheme (that doesn't mean they aren't there, I just haven't found any).

Comment: Oh  I am sorry. I think I missunderstood something. I thought the discounts in the question are actual discounts, which you packaged into a question to promote them here. :D I ll remove my downvote. "Price anomaly" in combination with "discount" sounds just a little bit shady. ^^